# Store 25 digit string of numbers in imageView.tag

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

How could I store a 25+ digit string containing digits i.e. (1234567890123456789012345) as a NSInteger in an imageView.tag and then later convert it back to it's original string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag of a UIImageView can hold 32 bits, at most, which is less than 10 independent digits.

You could subclass a UIImageView, and add your own tagObject property to it.  Then just use your new class and store an arbitrary length NSString in its tagObject.